# Ask Ubuntu newest questions bug?

Tags: bug, user-interface

I don't know if I'm the only one who faced this, but sometimes, when I am in [Ask Ubuntu newest questions page](https://askubuntu.com/questions) and someone posts a question, it shows the message: `(N) questions with new activity`, but sometimes, the grey bar won't show at all, I tried reloading the page, restarting the browser, but still doesn't work. Is it a bug, a browser-specific problem?

<sub>I'm using Google Chrome on Windows, this sometimes happens on Chrome for Ubuntu as well.</sub>

**<sub>EDIT: When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> or reload the page, I can see the new questions.</sub>**

**<sub>EDIT 2: It seems that not only the newest questions page, but also the questions have the same problem, I'm not getting the grey `1 new answers to this question` bar.</sub>**

Comment: Can you try pinging `sockets.ny.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: Also, try using http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/ to look at any websocket data. If you need to post it, ***be sure to strip it of the `fkey` parameter*** for your security.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ I tried following the guide, but as soon as I hit connect it shows `ERROR: undefined DISCONNECTED`

Comment: Looks like you aren't getting a WS connection. Can you ping as I gave in my above post?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ got the 4 answers back: `Answer from 64.34.119.101: bytes=32 time=152ms TTL=53`

Comment: What Chrome version?

Comment: Version 22.0.1229.94m